# Building a LINQ lambda expression that can output enums, decimals, and strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, linq-expressions

I am writing a re-usable view for my app. It uses a generic ViewModel `DynSingleView<T>`; you plug in the object type and the view will generate the property UI components to update them. It gets a little complex because instead of the ViewModel actually containing the data to be edited, it instead contains a list of `DisplayValue` objects, each of which represents (and contains metadata for) one property. Those can be used (via the PropertyInfo.GetValue() method) to retrieve the value from the generic object.

The major barrier is using the `Html.EditorFor` method. Using it will save me a lot of work in terms of reading from and writing to the property. However, to use it, I need to feed it a lambda expression that represents a simple property/field access (i.e. `model => model.Item.Property`).

I generate the expression using the following method in the ViewModel:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Given a property, returns a lambda expression that returns that property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dv">DisplayValue object, which is the property</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Expression<Func<DynSingleView<T>, TType>> GetExpression<TType>(DisplayValue dv)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DynSingleView<T>));
        var instance = Expression.Property(param, nameof(DynSingleView<T>.Item));
        var propertyCall = Expression.Property(instance, dv.PropertyName);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<DynSingleView<T>, TType>>(propertyCall, param);
        return lambda;
    }
```

This generates the needed lambda perfectly EXCEPT when it comes to enums. When I retrieve an enum property, I receive the following error on the lambda declaration line: `Expression of type MyProject.Model.Enums.MyEnum cannot be used for return type 'System.Enum'.`

I can't even convert it into an object in the lambda because the lambda needs to be a simple property access.

@Jose helped put together a linq expression that "fooled" the lambda expression into being created without an error and returning type 'System.Enum' (using that type for the generic parameter for 'Html.EnumDropDownListFor'), but that produced the error: `Return type 'System.Enum' is not supported.'` on the `Html.EnumDropDownListFor` line.

Here's the table inside the generic view:

```
<table border="1">
    @{
        foreach (var dv in Model.DisplayValues)
        {
            @:<tr><td>@dv.PropertyDisplayName</td><td>
            switch (dv.Type)
            {
                case DisplayValueType.Decimal:
                    @Html.EditorFor(Model.GetExpression<decimal>(dv));
                    break;
                case DisplayValueType.String:
                case DisplayValueType.Other:
                    @Html.EditorFor(Model.GetExpression<object>(dv));
                    break;
                //this is where I'm having trouble
                case DisplayValueType.PickList:
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(Model.GetExpression<object>(dv));
                    break;
            }
            @:</td></tr>
        }
    }
    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

It seems like the only way I can get this work is to specify the exact enum type, which makes the whole effort completely useless.

Please help!

Comment: I assume you looked into customizing scaffold templates but decided against it?

Comment: My knowledge of Asp.Net MVC isn't strong enough to say that wouldn't work, but I don't think it would.

To use the scaffolding, (I believe) you need a view that contains the various properties/fields to be edited. In this case, I am using a generic psuedo-view that stores those properties in a list.

Let me know if those limitations are self-imposed.

Comment: Sorry but where exactly are you getting the T type from. are you hard codding it in your view? `@model DynSingleView<Type1>.` And why would you want to do this when there are good dynamic overrides for editor and DropDown list?

Comment: Indeed, why bother with generic `XyzFor<T, P>(Expression<Func<T, P>> expression...)` methods, which are for static typing when you have a corresponding `Xyz(string expression...)` methods (`Xyz` - `Editor`, `DisplayName` etc.)

Comment: It's currently hard-coded in the view based on the categorization of the property; I'd love to refactor that out, but it's not a high priority. The purpose for the expression-based inputs is that they can bind to Model.item.Property instead of just Model.Property.

Answer (score 2):

I am 90% sure what you want is this

```
foreach (var dv in Model.DisplayValues)
        {
            @:<tr>
                <td>@dv.PropertyDisplayName</td>
                <td>
                switch (dv.Type)
                {
                    case DisplayValueType.Decimal:
                    case DisplayValueType.String:
                    case DisplayValueType.Other:
                    @Html.Editor("Item."+dv.PropertyName);
                    case DisplayValueType.PickList:
                    @Html.DropDownList("Item."+dv.PropertyName,EnumHelper.GetSelectList(Model.Item.GetType().GetProperty(dv.PropertyName).PropertyType));
                                                                                  break;
                }
                @:
            </td>
        </tr>
            }
```

Comment: The issue with this is that the value is not linked to the property of Model.Item, so when the model is submitted it will not assign the value of that dropdown to Model.Item.Property.

Comment: @Daniel Seams to me you already think you solved this and you just want someone to confirm that you have the solution. You are aware that the Generic [EditorFor](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/ValueExtensions.cs) just uses [Editor](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ExpressionHelper.cs) under the hood? So using "Item.Prop1" will do the same as m=>m.Item.Prop1. The method is just a helper for refactoring purposes.

Comment: My concern is that using the property name will bind the control to Model.Property (which doesn't exist) rather than Model.Item.Property. Am I incorrect?

Comment: @Daniel if you put the path  "ParentProp1.ChildProp1.ChildProp1" it will be bound to the path. What this is doing is setting the name attribute on the input element and the form is sending it back as form data P1.C1 = your value. You can test this using fiddler.

Comment: I understand now. I didn't understand the back-end mechanism for binding; now that I do your solution makes perfect sense. Of course, now when I try to post the model it says Model.Item is null.... but that's a topic for a different question. :)

Comment: (Never mind... that was just a result of sheer idiocy. It works now! It's magical! Thanks. :))

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want static type checking, you must treat each `enum` as a separate type (like you do `Decimal` and `String`) and give them their own cases that are the same except for the type.

Answer (score 0):

> you plug in the object type and the view will generate the property UI components to update them.

You can use [EditorTemplates](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm) to do this. Create an EditorTemplate for each type you wish to edit. MVC resolves these at run-time, so you could have 10 different types and it will generate different HTML for each:

Action

```
List<object> model = new List<object>
{
    "hello world",
    123,
    true,
};

return View(model);
```

View chooses EditorTemplate at runtime

```
@model List<object>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i])   // textbox, numerical textbox, then checkbox
}
```

~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml

```
@model string

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m)
```

and so on. It's an extreme example - normally you would use a base class rather than object.

You may get problems when they are posted back, the MVC model binder may not recognise the different types by default. You could fix that by writing a custom model-binder.

Answer (score -1):

You can cast the property to TType and then use it as the parameter to the lambda.

```
var convert = Expression.Convert(propertyCall, typeof(TType));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<DynSingleView<T>, TType>>(convert, param);
```

Comment: I did try this; unfortunately the Html helper methods I referenced only accept simple property access.

Comment: Is this possible?
`if (typeof(TType) == typeof(Enum))
    {
 var convert = Expression.Convert(propertyCall, typeof(TType));
 var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<DynSingleView<T>, TType>>(convert, param);
 return (f) => lambda.Compile()(this);
}`

Comment: No, it still produces an expression other than a simple property access. I did give it a shot though just in case.

Comment: Of course! I wonder if you can fool it with something like this:`var o = new { Name = (TType) lambda.Compile()(this)}; var anonParam = Expression.Constant(o, o.GetType()); var anonProperty = Expression.Property(anonParam, nameof(o.Name)); var lambda2 =Expression.Lambda<Func<DynSingleView<T>, TType>>(anonProperty, param); return lambda2;`

Comment: Gave it a try. Nope, but that was very creative!

Comment: You can try returning Expression without specifying the Lambda func returned. `public Expression GetExpression(DisplayValue dv)
 {
  var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DynSingleView<T>));
  var instance = Expression.Property(param, nameof(DynSingleView<T>.Item));
  var propertyCall = Expression.Property(instance, dv.PropertyName);        
  var lambda = Expression.Lambda(propertyCall, param);
  return lambda;  
 }`

Comment: That did at least get me a new error! The EnumDropDownListFor says "Return type 'System.Enum' is not supported." I've added this to the main question.